# Semantic MediaWiki: Use template results in #switch

Tags: switch-statement, mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I want to #switch cases within an #ask-template but it looks like #switch ignores the given result value of {{{2}}} and always displays the #default.
Is there a way to accomplish this? Am I missing something?
Thank you very much!

List:

```
{{#ask: [[Kategorie:Cat1]]
| ?Arg1
| ?Arg2
| ?Arg3
| ?Arg4
| format=template
| template=TableContent
| introtemplate=TableHeader
| outrotemplate=TableFooter
| sort=Name
| link=none
}}
```

Tablecontent:

```
<includeonly>
<tr>
 <td>[[{{{1}}}]]</td>
 <td>
  {{#switch: {{{2}}}
  | Case1 = [[File:icon1.png|24px|link=]] Case1
  | Case2 = [[File:icon2.png|24px|link=]] Case2
  | Case3 = [[File:icon3.png|24px|link=]] Case3
  | #default = bla
  }}
 </td>
 <td>{{{3}}}</td>
 <td>{{#if:{{{4|}}}|{{{4}}}| }}</td>
</tr>
</includeonly>
```

Single page:

```
<!-- SMW code -->
<span style="display:none">
 [[Kategorie:Cat1]]
 [[Kategorie:Cat2]]
 [[Arg1::{{PAGENAME}}]]
 [[Arg2::Case2]]
 [[Arg3::3x2]]
 [[Arg4::foo]]
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

`{{{1}}}` is always the page title in SMWs template results format, therefor in your switch you need to use `{{{3}}}`, see https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Template_format#Using_templates_for_custom_formatting

Answer (score 0):

If you set named args=yes as a parameter of your ask query things might get simpler and clearer.

see:
https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Named_args

Instead of {{{2}}} you'd use {{{?Args2}}} or {{{Args2}}} depending on your SMW Version (see link above).

Also you might want to provide a default e.g. use {{{Args2|}}}. There is also a Sandbox Wiki at https://sandbox.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Main_Page in which you can tryout your approach so that people can follow your example better.